# Android: Firebase Anonymous Authentication

Tags: android, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

When using anonymous authentication with firebase, the first time the app is launched from android studio (if it's uninstalled), a firebase account is created as intended, but the firebase database references don't connect. Only when launching the app a second time, the references work as intended and I can upload and retrieve data with my code. I'm guessing some stuff isn't initialized properly.

**My code for anonymous authentication**

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    var challenges = ArrayList<Challenge?>()
    val recyclerViewAdapter = RecyclerViewAdapter(challenges)
    var currentChallengeActive: Boolean = false

    companion object{
        var mAuth: FirebaseAuth? = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
        val userId = mAuth?.currentUser?.uid
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()

        startService(Intent(this, MyService::class.java))
        setFragment()
        val currentUser = mAuth?.currentUser
        if (currentUser == null){
            anonymousLogin()
        }

    private fun anonymousLogin() {
        mAuth?.signInAnonymously()?.addOnCompleteListener { task ->
            if (task.isSuccessful) {
                Snackbar.make(
                    findViewById(R.id.constraint_layout),
                    "Logged in anonymously",
                    Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT
                ).show()
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Login fehlgeschlagen", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        }
    }
```

**My firebase references**

```
class FirebaseConfig {

    companion object{

        var database: FirebaseDatabase? = null
        var myRootRef: DatabaseReference? = null
        var completedChallengesRef: DatabaseReference? = null
        var openChallengesRef: DatabaseReference? = null
        var swappedChallengesRef: DatabaseReference? = null

        init {
            database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
            myRootRef = userId?.let { database?.getReference("users")?.child(it) }
            completedChallengesRef = userId?.let { database?.getReference("users")?.child(it)?.child("completed") }
            openChallengesRef = userId?.let { database?.getReference("users")?.child(it)?.child("open") }
            swappedChallengesRef = userId?.let { database?.getReference("users")?.child(it)?.child("swapped") }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! You seem to be connecting the db paths *before* authentication has taken place (when `userId` would still be `null`). Instead lazily initialise those paths with a `GetDatabasePaths` method or something similar, after you've logged the user in. It's important to remember that most firebase calls are asynchronous. Your excessive use of `?` operators is silencing the errors that would point this out.

Comment: What you are looking for is explained in this article, [How to handle Firebase Authentication in clean architecture using Jetpack Compose?](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-handle-firebase-authentication-in-clean-architecture-using-jetpack-compose-e9929c0e31f8). It contains a video and Github repo.